# On a mac Big Sur v 11.6, the terminal won't let me run anything with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-big-sur

I just installed python 3.10 and I followed a tutorial that told me to create an alias so that the pre-installed 2.7.6 won't run. I tried to use

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and add

```
alias python="python3"
```

but that wouldn't work to change my version.

Then I tried using

```
nano ~/.zprofile
```

and add

```
alias python="python3"
```

Now everytime I run a simple python file that tries to execute print("hello world"), it comes up with **SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal**. There is no variable in the python code.

```
@Carters-MBP ~ % python3 Desktop/intro.p.py
  File "/Users/carternetzley/Desktop/intro.p.py", line 1
    Python 3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @wjandrea I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

Opinionated answer follows...

Don't use aliases for Python. They don't work very well:

- in IDEs, or
- `cron` jobs or
- subprocesses or non-interactive logins.

Remove all Python aliases and restart your machine.

Use the `type` command to find out what is actually run when you execute a command. So if you want to know what your shell will actually run when you do `python3`, use:

```
type python3
```

If you want to know what your shell will run when you do `python`, use:

```
type python
```

---

Your shell doesn't *"prevent"* you running anything! It simply runs the first matching thing you have in your PATH.

So if you have installed Python 3.10 at `/Applications/Python3.10/bin/python`, simply set your PATH to:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Python3.10/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all in your file.  What you have in `intro.p.py` is not a Python script, it is a transcript of a terminal session.  It includes the Python header line which, of course, is not valid code.  You need to edit that file and make it a Python script.